# Кросс компиляция для raspberry pi 2

Tags: java, c++, qt, arm

Будет ли приложение(простой сервер для локальной станицы) написанное на java и собранное в исполняемый файл запускаться на малине? Или лучше на C++ и кросскомпилятор? Сишник знаю существенно лучше java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPI - это полноценный комп с unix/linux (и Win10, при желании), а не просто какой-то микроконтроллер.

Приложения на java, собранные в jar, или собранные прямо на самой малинке - отлично работают и запускаются.

Приложения на C++ так же вполне будут работать, но собирать вам их придется скорее всего на самой RPI.